# "export" a tuple from function to a global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, listbox

I programmed a function that extracts the selected options in a listbox with Tkinter. The print commands only works if I wrtite it directly in the function. How can i print the tuple outside of the function?

This is the failure code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/....", line 68, in <module>
    print (selection)
NameError: name 'selection' is not defined
```

I tried to transform the tuple to a global variable.

````py
    def doStuff():
        global selected
        selected = lb.curselection()
        if selected: # only perform  if user made a selection
            for index in selected:
                selection = (lb.get(index))# how you get the value of the selection from a listbox
    print(selection)
    ```
````

Comment: 1) You never call your function. 2) You should look into a `return` statement and probably follow a python tutorial.  If you want to start getting into coding you will found that a tutorial will provide a great foundation to build off of.

Comment: Also please choose either Python2.7 or Python3. Don't choose both (they are not the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below to access `selection` outside the function scope. But remember to call `doStuff()` function before printing the `selection` variable outside the function's scope.

```
selected = None 
selection = None

def doStuff():
        global selected, selection
        selected = lb.curselection()
        if selected: # only perform  if user made a selection
            for index in selected:
                selection = (lb.get(index))# how you get the value of the selection from a listbox
print(selection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables set inside of a function will only be accessible from within it. You need to add `return selection` to the end of the function, then do `print(doStuff())`

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: with your changes I  get this failure :SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: The return statement needs to be inside the function, at one indentation level

Comment: Technically internal variables can be assigned to global ones (though not recommend). Similarly you can assign method variables to class instance ones.  You could also make the function a generator where you can access the variables. Not a bad answer but I would be careful using words like "only" or "can't" when answering a question.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will make it better the next time.